# Finding turtles with lowest variable in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am simulating passengers leaving from terminal, I would like to pick the passengers with the earliest arrival time to board a plane. I am using hidden turtles as the passengers to be able to measure their waiting time, and would need to pick the 4 earliest arrived passengers to board (to stop their wait time counters by having them die) All the passenger turtles have a variable called passenger number that denotes when they arrived at the terminal, how do I find all the 4 lowest passenger number passenger turtles every time I want to board those passengers?

Comment: In the NetLogo dictionary, look up `n-min-of`

Comment: do you mean min-n-of?

Comment: yes, sorry wasn't paying attention